# Mongoose Async Accessors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider the Schemas

```
const Person = Schema({
    name: String,
    pets: {
       type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
       ref: 'Pets'
    }
})

const Pet = Schema({
    name: String,
    color: String
})
```

How is it possible on `Person.findBy(personId)` to return the following and not an array of ids?

```
{
    name: 'John Doe',
    pets: [
        { name: 'Lilah', color: 'white' },
        { name: 'Hanna', color: 'brown' }
    ]
}
```

I Tried to use mongoose async accessors

```
const Person = Schema ({
    ...
    
     pets: {
         type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
         ref: 'Pets',
         get: async pets => Pets.find({ '_id': { $id: pets} })
      }
    
    ...
})
```

But feels like overengineering (and it runs the function everytime the property is accessed)

Comment: are you using express.js?

Comment: `Person.findById(personId).populate('pets')...` See the docs for `populate` here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html